# Help with my PCB connection. Seems reversed

Tags: pcb, proteus

[image]

Done this in Proteus. I printed this out in the copper board and soldered components.
But turns out my relay did not work.

I used a 9V battery in the the supposed to be 5 volts for the Arduino because I still don't have one. I have two separate batteries.

Put the power wire in the transistor base, connected transistor emitter to the GND did not switch my relay, doing it reverse switched my relay though and I don't understand why?

I'm not good in electronics that's why I'm trying out things. But why did my relay switch with the battery GND in transistor base and power in the emitter?

And my 470ohms resistor is not working I'm directly putting connection in the transistor base where it worked. I used a 2N2222 instead of a 2N3903, and a DEC DI1U relay. I used a tester to check if connection is good. My soldering is clean and I don't know what to do now.

My problem is that my resistor is not working, connection seems reversed and I'm a noob so big problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct connection is like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fahEDY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also note that there are a few different pinouts for 2N2222, make sure that you have connected the transistor correctly depending on the case used.

[image]

Comment: I used multisim to simulate my circuit. ,nothing seems to be the problem. and its just the same isn't it? I just forgot to put the GND, but on pcb layout its just the output.

Comment: and I use the one in the middle. ,

Comment: @aLzyAruManaois But in your schematic you show the + of 9v and + of 5v connected to the emitter, that is not what is shown in my schematic, how are they the same? The ground in not a problem, it can either be there or not.

Comment: yes, but they're just terminal blocks. so in my pcb I just switch wire + to +, - to - .. i also turned my transistor so that the collector is to source and emitter is to ground.,

but when I apply power to the collector my relay won't switch, instead when I put the power in the emitter and GND in the collector it flicks.

Comment: @aLzyAruManaois In your PCB you shown the + of 9v connected with the - of 5v so it's still not shown correctly.
You mentioned in one part of your reply that you have tried driving the transistor base without the resistor, if you did you probably destroyed the transistor so you may want to try a new one. If you wire everything as I show in the schematic and it doesn't work then you have some damaged component (unless the battery is not strong enough to drive the relay). I also hope the 5v source can provide enough current to drive the 120 OHm resistor.

Comment: I really don't know how much resistance to use, I don't understand hfe and things. And is the transistor I used alright?what would you recommend sir?

Comment: and I did my schematic on breadboard before printing it, and it worked. so maybe my transistor's dead. can too much heat damage the transistor sir? because it got so heated up when I soldered it.

Comment: @aLzyAruManaois The base current should be about 1/10 to 1/20 of the output current to saturate the transistor and have a low emitter-collector voltage drop. The calculation is Ibase=(Vin-0.7v)/R. With the resistor you have used the base current is about 4.3v/120=33mA, that is on the high side to drive a relay that normally needs up to 100mA (although I don't know the specs of your relay).

Comment: yes, I changed that and used 4.7kOhms as to what I saw from an schematic that's just the same.,but when I used it when testing on breadboard I can't seem to drive my relay.but it works when I remove my resistor.

Comment: http://www.sanyourelay.ca/public/products/pdf/DI1U-K.pdf
I use this relay, although mine is DEC not sanyou, because the guy from the store insist that they're the same and I think he know what he's doing and hey they look the same so what heck.

Comment: @aLzyAruManaois That relay needs about 100mA max (9v model) or lower for the 12v model. 10mA will be more than enough, 4.3v/0.01A = 430 Ohm, so 470 Ohm would be fine. 4k7 is too high , it can't drive the relay.

Comment: Nice, so my 470Ohms will do then. I'll just look into my connections further and make sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Both low voltage connectors on your schematic are marked with reverse polarity.
2. Try to keep 220V traces on PCB as far as you can from low voltage side. I suggest turning relay 90 degrees CW.
3. You don't need to make traces of one width throughout your PCB. 220V traces could be made wider.

Comment: On the PCB 5V connector polarity marking is reversed again, though pin numbers correspond to schematic. So it's polarity marking is correct now :-)  But 9V is still backwards.

Comment: but I put the wiring accordingly. and disregard the 5V terminal block because im directing it with a 9V battery and that's why im putting the positive in the GND and the GND to the suppose to be source of my transistor.

Comment: and how would it affect my pcb if high voltage where near low voltage sir? I thought it was far away enough. to keep my pcb small.,

Comment: Rotating relay would not make your PCB bigger, but will make it a little bit safer. This is a general advice, related not to the issue we are discussing, but for amateur PCB routing in general.